# ReferenceError: Left side of assignment is not a reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with some reference error:

> Left side of assignment is not a reference.

I want to do with that code to type in textarea only these regexNounFilters.

```
$('#toFile').on('keypress', function() {
    onInput($('#toFile'));
});

const regexNounFilters = [<?php
        $data = $pdo->query("SELECT PRODUCT_CODE AS code, ENDING AS ec FROM test")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach ($data as $key) {
            $separator = ($key != end($data)) ? ", " : '';
            $std = "/^(" . $key->code . ")([a-zA-Z0-9]{" . $key->ec . "})$/";
            echo $std.$separator;
        }
    ?>];

    const extractNouns = string =>
      string
      .split('\n')
      .filter(line =>
        regexNounFilters.some(re =>
          line.trim().toUpperCase().match(re)
        )
    );

    function onInput({target}) {
      target.val() = extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'); // error points here...
      console.log(target.val());
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Help us out. :-) Tell us what line the error is pointing to.

Comment: (I found it. But it's always best to say.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I pointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:

```js
target.val() = extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n')
```

You can't assign to the result of a function call.

You probably want that line to be:

```js
target.val(extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'))
```

For more info see the [jQuery `val()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

---

#### Another issue

You are passing the changed element but are then accessing the `target` property on that by destructuring.

```js
$('#toFile').on('keypress', function() {
    onInput($('#toFile')) // <- passing the element here
})

function onInput({target}) { // <- destructuring that element to get the target
    target.val(extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'))
    console.log(target.val())
}
```

You either want:

```js
$('#toFile').on('keypress', function() {
    onInput($('#toFile')) // <- passing the element here
})

function onInput(target) { // <- directly accessing it
    target.val(extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'))
    console.log(target.val())
}
```

or

```js
$('#toFile').on('keypress', function(e) {
    onInput(e) // <- passing the error args here
})

function onInput({target}) { // <- destructuring to get the target
    target.val(extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'))
    console.log(target.val())
}
```

Comment: getting error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'target.val')`

Comment: You are trying to access the target property of `$('#toFile')`. Either change `{target}` to `target` or pass the event arguments instead of `$('#toFile')`.

Comment: changed to `target` and code doesnt work.. shows only in textarea pressed key and if I press another key it deletes last key.. But I want type only `regexNounFilters` in textarea.

Comment: If you have a different question you need to ask a new question with details of what isn't working. My answer should solve the issue you outlined in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign to the result of calling a function here:

```
function onInput({target}) {
  target.val() = extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n');
// -----^^^^^^^^^
  console.log(target.val());
}
```

You can't do that. To set the input's value, pass the value into the [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
  target.val(extractNouns(target.val()).join('\n'));
```

---

Note that you're using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameter list of that function:

```
function onInput({target}) {
// --------------^------^
```

That will try to pick out a `target` property from what's passed in, and give you that property's value instead of what was passed in. Based on how you're callilng it, you don't want to use destructuring there:

```
function onInput(target) {
```

Comment: getting error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'target.val')`

Comment: @Kizzie - That's a **different** problem. This is the answer to the question you actually asked. :-) But I've edited in a note about that problem too.